# Need these AJAX calls to happen after the previous one is finished

Tags: .net, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a JavaScript method that is ran after a user selects certain check-boxes. This method makes one AJAX call to render a "header" view, and then makes an AJAX call for each of the selected check-boxes, and then appends those views as well.

The issue is that when I'm looping through the check-boxes with JQuery and making an AJAX call for each of them, it's just making a bunch of AJAX calls one after the other in the right order, but they get rendered at different times depending on how long each one takes. I guess this is the beauty of AJAX, but I need it to render in the order I call them for this specific task.

Here is the method:

```
function GenerateTermSheet()
{
    var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/RenderPartialTermSheetView")%>";
    var jsonNickname = 
    {
        id : GetGUIDValue(),
        viewName : 'Nickname'
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlString,
        data: jsonNickname,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data);
        }
    });
    $('#termSheetPopup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        var checkedName = $(this).attr("name");
        var json = 
        {
            id : GetGUIDValue(),
            viewName : checkedName
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlString,
            data: json,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data);
            }
        });
    })
    $('#termSheetPopup').dialog('close');
    $('#termSheetPrinted').dialog('open');
}
```

Know how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why make a bunch of AJAX calls? Why not send the data all in one AJAX call and handle it in order on the server-side? If you're having one happen right after another, then no input is required by the user, so you can achieve the same effect.

Comment: So make one AJAX call sending in the Guid along with a list of all the checked names? The only thing is, my controller method is returning views, then the JQuery is appending the returned view to the div. How would I return a bunch of views at once from one controller action?

Comment: @slandau - Can you just return a single view (that you have built up server-side)? This puts full control server-side for you and then you don't have to worry about synchronizing your AJAX calls (which, consequently, is pretty inefficient and goes against the entire idea behind AJAX (with the first word of the acronym being Asynchronous)). Send everything once, do all your work on the back end, build the return result, and send it on back and display the new view. Does that help?

Comment: That does help however we have already built out an entire infrastructure of different views that the controller decides where to go to render them, and that work is already in place working fine, they just got a little angry when the order of the views started switching around because some took longer than others to render, so, your re-factor is a great idea for the future, but for the time being switching the async switch is the easiest way to seal the deal (terrible I know, but we'll fix it up sooner of later).

Comment: @slandau - No problem. :-) Glad you like the alternate solution. And, I definitely understand about having to meet customers needs like...yesterday. But, if you do get an opportunity to refactor, go for it. If done correctly, it's likely the customers won't even notice, but you'll make life a lot easier for yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest placing the second AJAX call within a function that is called in the success function of the call that must be completed first. This will cause the second call to only execute if the first was successful, and will achieve the goal you were seeking.

Comment: So, basically, wrap the rest of the function within the success. Or if you don't care about success, use complete instead

Comment: Since it's looping through items though and making an AJAX call for each one, how would I embed that? If I was making one call I could see how putting it under 'success' or 'complete' would make sense, but putting a loop of AJAX calls under a 'success' or 'complete' would just perform that whole loop the same way, and only validate that the first call gets rendered first, not all calls within the loop.

Comment: Ah, I missed the .Each in there. Well, turning off the async property would kinda defeat the purpose of using Ajax in the first place...but it may work for you. Outside of that, I'm slightly sunk as to how to manage a recursive loop. Though in answer to your question in the comments, you could always build a IList of Views and then convert it to json and parse it from there into your div...

Comment: I guess that is one option (the List), however let me try and see if the turning off async works or not. The users of that app really don't need an async user experience for this specific task.